# I cannot run kubectl get nodes as root. Why?

Tags: kubernetes

On my master node

```
root@k8smaster:~# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
root@k8smaster:~# exit
logout

yoda@k8smaster:~/bin$ kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8smaster   Ready     master    5d        v1.9.2
k8sworker   Ready     <none>    51s       v1.9.2
```

Why do I need to run kubectl as my own user ?

Comment: My hunch is that your root user doesn't have access to the cluster configured. What does `ls -al ~/.kube/config` give you when you're root? Also, does actually *any* kubectl command work under root? Try for example `kubectl version --short`.

Comment: The config file is owned by yoda:yoda with 600 permission. Running the version command did print the Client version but failed with the same ``connection to localhost:8080 refused``. This is my first time installing k8s with kubeadm; so I'm probably making all kinds of stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Michael said is exactly accurate; `kubectl` looks in the *current user's* home directory, which for `yoda` will likely be `/home/yoda` but for root is almost certainly `/root`.

You can very quickly test this theory by re-running your `kubectl` command with an explicit `--kubeconfig ~yoda/.kube/config`:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig ~yoda/.kube/config get nodes
```

You can also export the shell variable `KUBECONFIG` to avoid having to constantly include that long `--kubeconfig` syntax:

```
export KUBECONFIG=~yoda/.kube/config
kubectl get nodes
```

Ensure you don't put any characters between the `~` and `yoda` or it will look for a `yoda` directory inside the current user's home directory.

Comment: I added KUBECONFIG for the root user and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl` needs `kubeconfig` at `$HOME/.kube/config` by default.

Kubeadm puts the original `kubeconfig` in `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`.

Any user (including root) can do the following to get `kubeconfig` in the current user's home directory at `$HOME/.kube/config`:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Alternatively, if you are the `root` user, you can run this:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```